# I have to delete some rows from two tables which are connected with a foreign key on the basis of counts

Tags: mysql

I have two tables called property and tanks, any property can have one or more than one contacts, in tanks table I have propertyid as foreign key. I want to delete the properties based on the number of tanks. 
Here is the query which is not working

```
DELETE  P FROM properties P
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT T.Id 
   FROM tanks T 
   GROUP BY T.PropertyID 
   HAVING COUNT(T.ID) = 2
 ) T ON T.PropertyId = P.ID
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working are you getting errors or no rows are deleted etc ?

Comment: Hi Junaid, It was giving the error like "T.PropertyId is not recognized as column". Now I got the solution, I am selecting only Id (T.Id) thats why it was not recognizing the propertyid column. I gave T.* and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
DELETE p.* FROM properties p 
JOIN tanks t 
ON p.id=t.property_id 
GROUP BY t.property_id 
HAVING COUNT(t.id)=2;
```